# slice dataframe inplace and dynamically rename in a loop

Tags: pandas

I am aware that it may not be good practice but I am curious to know if it is possible to take two dfs (in this case, srm and srae), take a slice of each, and then rename this sliced dataframes as srm1 and srae1.

The logic is below.

```
for x in (srm, srae):
    x1 = x[x['years_in_role']>5]
    print(x.shape, x1.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpack 2 tuples to 2 variables:

```
srm1, srae1 = [x[x['years_in_role']>5] for x in (srm, srae)]
```

Your solution should be used for create list and then create new variables:

```
L = []
for x in (srm, srae):
    x1 = x[x['years_in_role']>5]
    L.append(x1)

srm1 = L[0]
srae1 = L[1]
```